# How to work on a portion of a histogram in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, histogram

[image]

Hi! I have come up with a bimodal graph like this on which I want to find min, max, mode, median and standard deviation of distribution. But I am only interested on a portion of this complete histogram. I want to find these values only for the left side of it (that is for the left mode and its surroundings). So for this reason I want to divide the histogram into two parts based on X axis ([0, 0.25] and [0.25, 0.4] say) before passing it to respective numpy/statistics/scipy functions. I want to pass the [0, 0.25] portion only. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You need to provide the data structure that was used for the histogram.

Comment: @Fourier I am not quite sure about what back-end data-structure they have used but I used pandas.DataFrame.plot.hist to plot this histogram from a csv file containing two attribute columns.

Comment: This is what I was asking for. `freq, division = pandas.np.histogram(df[0])` will give you the frequencies and bins for the given column `0`. Now try selection by `freq[freq <= 0.25]` and `division[freq <= 0.25]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write you used a pandas dataframe to plot it. So I am assuming you have a dataframe to work on.

If you only want to pass values between an interval you can slice it using pandas slicing, this is assuming your X data is stored in a column called "X":

```
from_x = 0
to_x = 0.25
data_with_values_in_X_interval= data[(data["X"] >= from_x) & (data["X"] <= to_x)]
```

Then you can plot the DataFrame the same way as you did before